# How do I order a model, based on multiple values from a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Basically, I need to order, based on multiple values from a ManyToManyField.

So what I want to achieve is having the objects with the most questioned values on top, continuing with objects that have less of the questioned values. Continuing with objects that don't have any of these values.

The models:

```
    class Color(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Item(models.Model):
        surface_color = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
```

---

The instances created which are based on the models above:

- Item 1) surface_color=[1, 2, 3]
- Item 2) surface_color=[1, 2]
- Item 3) surface_color=[2]
- Item 4) surface_color=[1, 3]

---

Now I need to order based multiple colors:

Fake query: `Item.objects.all().order_by(surface_color_id=[1, 3])`

The query should have the following results:

1. Item 4, since it has both 1 and 3
2. Item 1, since it has both 1 and 3
3. Item 2, since it has 1
4. Item 3, since it has none

---

Is this possible with a single queryset? Or do I need to spam multiple queries for each combination?

The only things I found on the internet were about ordering multiple **fields**, this is about **values**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not at all clear how your desired ordering relates to the data. Can you please explain further?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm sorry, does this help a bit?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I guess not, please tell me what I need to explain. :(

Comment: It does help explain what you want (although I'm still unclear on whether there's any significance to the ordering of items 4 and 1). Unfortunately I can't think of a good way of achieving it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There is none, 4 and 1 have two matches, 3 has one match, and the last has no match.

Comment: you seem to arbitarily asign an ordering. How is django or the database supposed to know that? You will have to come up with a mechanism to tell the database what you have in your mind. how about a column specially for ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
list(Item.objects.filter(surface_color__in=[1,3]).distinct().annotate(num_colors=Count('surface_color')).order_by('-num_colors')) + list(Item.objects.exclude(surface_color__in=[1,3]).distinct())
```

It requires two queries, though you don't need a separate query for each Item.

---

#### Same logic broken down with comments:

```
# Make sure you import Count somewhere in the file first
from django.db.models import Count

# id of Color objects to match
color_ids_to_match = [1,3]

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Item objects with Color objects matching `color_ids_to_match`
# - The `surface_color` field has **at least one** Color object with a matching id from `color_ids_to_match`
# - This matches Items #4, #1, #2 from your sample data
items_with_matching_color = Item.objects.filter(surface_color__in=color_ids_to_match).distinct()

# Adds a select field to the query to track the number of surface_color objects matched
# - **NOT the total** number of Color objects associated through `surface_color`
items_with_matching_color = items_with_matching_color.annotate(num_colors=Count('surface_color'))

# Order by that field in descending order
# - Note that the order is undetermined between Item objects with the same `num_colors` value
items_with_matching_color = items_with_matching_color.order_by('-num_colors')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Item objects **NOT** associated with any Color objects with a id in `color_ids_to_match`
# - This matches Item #3 from your sample data
items_without_matching_color = Item.objects.exclude(surface_color__in=color_ids_to_match).distinct()

# Optional - Sets the num_colors field to 0 for this queryset in case you need this information
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
items_without_matching_color = items_without_matching_color.annotate(num_colors=RawSQL('0', ()))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Convert the two querysets to lists and concatenate them
# - This is necessary because a simple queryset union such as `items_with_matching_color | items_without_matching_color`
#   does not maintain the order between the two querysets
ordered_items = list(items_with_matching_color) + list(items_without_matching_color)
```

#### Output using your sample data:

```
>>> ordered_items
[<Item: 1: <QuerySet [<Color: 1>, <Color: 2>, <Color: 3>]>>, <Item: 4: <QuerySet [<Color: 1>, <Color: 3>]>>, <Item: 2: <QuerySet [<Color: 1>, <Color: 2>]>>, <Item: 3: <QuerySet [<Color: 2>]>>]
```

Note that here, item 1 is before item 4. You mentioned that the order between the two doesn't matter since they both matched the same number of Color objects. You can add another parameter to `order_by` to further refine the ordering for your needs.

#### Getting the number of matching Color objects:

```
<Item: 1: <QuerySet [<Color: 1>, <Color: 2>, <Color: 3>]>>
>>> ordered_items[0].num_colors
2
>>> ordered_items[1]
<Item: 4: <QuerySet [<Color: 1>, <Color: 3>]>>
>>> ordered_items[1].num_colors
2
>>> ordered_items[2]
<Item: 2: <QuerySet [<Color: 1>, <Color: 2>]>>
>>> ordered_items[2].num_colors
1
>>> ordered_items[3]
<Item: 3: <QuerySet [<Color: 2>]>>
>>> ordered_items[3].num_colors
0
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have Postgres tables named `items`, `colors`, and `item_surface_colors`, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM   items
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_surface_colors isc
ON     isc.item_id = items.id
AND    isc.surface_color_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY items.id
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT isc.surface_color_id) DESC
```

I could tell you how to perform that query in ActiveRecord, but for Django I'm afraid you're on your own. :-)

There is the `raw(...)` method to perform raw SQL queries, but make sure you parameterize your input to prevent SQL injections (I have not done this here).  Read more about performing raw sql queries in Django here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/

```py
Item.objects.raw("SELECT items.* \
FROM   items \
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_surface_colors isc \
ON     isc.item_id = items.id \
AND    isc.surface_color_id IN (1,3) \
GROUP BY items.id \
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT isc.surface_color_id) DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could sum the IDs of whatever it meets. It won't work for much larger ID sets, but if its only these (which I doubt)...

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Item.objects.annotate(my_order=Sum('surface_color__id')).order_by('-my_order')
```

Answer (score 0):

For every `color_id` you want to order, you need to make a `subquery` and mark `True/False` whether that row has this `color_id`.
Let's say you have a [`ItemQuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) class, then you can abstract your order logic in a following fashion:

```
class ItemQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def order_by_colors(self, color_ids):
        extra_kwargs = {
            'select': {},
            'select_params' = [],
            'order_by': []
        }

        for (index, color_id) in enumerate(color_ids):
            order_by_key = 'color_%s' % index
            extra_kwargs['select'][order_by_key] = """EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM myapp_item_colors
                WHERE myapp_item_colors.color_id = %s
                    AND myapp_item_colors.item_id = myapp_item.id)"""
            extra_kwargs['select_params'].append(color_id)
            extra_kwargs['order_by'].append('-%s' % order_by_key)

        return self.extra(**extra_kwargs)

#usage
Item.objects.all().order_by_colors([1, 3])
```